# "ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Candidate,1} at index [1]" when trying to fill the empty array of a composite type

Tags: arrays, julia, composite

I get an error when trying to populate an empty array with input from a user.

```
const max = 9 # a maximal number of candidates

# Let us define a composite type for the candidates in our elections
mutable struct Candidate
    name::String
    votes::Int8
 end
 
 
candidates = Candidate[]

i = 1

while i < max
 println("Name of the candidate: ?")
 candidates[i].name = readline();
 println("Votes on him: ?")
 candidates[i].votes = parse(Int8, readline(), base=10);
 println("Thank you, let us move to the next candidate.")
 global i = i +1    
 end
```

After ("Name of the candidate: ?") being displayed, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Candidate,1} at index [1]
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{Candidate,1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:731
 [2] top-level scope at /home/jerzy/ComputerScience/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/MyJulia/plurality.jl:18 [inlined]
 [3] top-level scope at ./none:0
 [4] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [7] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:266
 [8] _start() at ./client.jl:425
in expression starting at /home/jerzy/ComputerScience/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/MyJulia/plurality.jl:16
```

Alternatively, using

```
candidates = Array{Candidate}(undef, 0)
```

instead of

```
candidates = Candidate[]
```

results in:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
```

Apologies for being such a newbie. I relied on [what I read in this wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Arrays_and_tuples#Creating_simple_arrays). Would you refer me to some more reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost correct, issue is that the length of your array is 0 (you can verify it with `length(candidates)`), so Julia complains when you are trying to set non-zero indexed elements of an array with `candidates[i]`. If you do not know length of your array in advance, then you should use [push!](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.push!) function.

```
const max_candidates = 9 # a maximal number of candidates

while i < max_candidates
 println("Name of the candidate: ?")
 name = readline();
 println("Votes on him: ?")
 votes = parse(Int, readline());
 push!(candidates, Candidate(name, votes))
 println("Thank you, let us move to the next candidate.")
 global i = i + 1
end
```

I've changed here `max` to `max_candidates` because `max` interferes with Base `max` function.

If you know number of candidates, you can use `candidates = Vector{Candidate}(undef, max_candidates)` form of initialization, take notice of `max_candidates` instead of `0`, because you should allocate vector of necessary length.

```
candidates = Vector{Candidate}(undef, max_candidates)

for i in 1:max_candidates
 println("Name of the candidate: ?")
 name = readline();
 println("Votes on him: ?")
 votes = parse(Int, readline());
 candidates[i] = Candidate(name, votes)
 println("Thank you, let us move to the next candidate.")
end
```

Take notice, that I changed `while` to `for` it may be or may be not useful in your case, but at least that lets you remove `global i = i + 1` line.

If the last version suits you, then you could probably remove `mutable` from struct definition, it is usually better for performance.

Comment: I've missed the fact that readlines for `votes` returns `String` and not number.

Unless you have very limited memory resources, it is safe to use just `Int` instead of any concrete types like `Int8` or `Int32` or any else. Also, by default base = 10, so it can be omitted.

it also could make sense to add additional constructor to separate parsing and questionnare logic
`Candidate(name::AbstractString, votes::AbstractString) = Candidate(name, parse(Int, votes))`

This way you can concentrate purely on the user interaction part.